# How to exclude remotely added listview from pull using .forceignore

Tags: salesforcedx, list-view, .forceignore

When I run command:

```
sfdx force:source:status
```

I get output:

```
Remote Add      ClaimCoverage.All_ClaimCoverages                                 ListView
Remote Add      ClaimCoverage.My_RecentClaimCoverages                            ListView
Remote Add      ClaimPaymentSummary.All_ClaimPaymentSummaries                    ListView
Remote Add      ClaimPaymentSummary.My_RecentClaimPaymentSummaries               ListView
Remote Add      InsurancePolicySurcharge.All_InsurancePolicySurcharges           ListView
Remote Add      InsurancePolicySurcharge.My_RecentInsurancePolicySurcharges      ListView
Remote Add      InsurancePolicyTransaction.All_InsurancePolicyTransactions       ListView
Remote Add      InsurancePolicyTransaction.My_RecentInsurancePolicyTransactions  ListView
Remote Add      ProducerCommission.All_ProducerCommissions                       ListView
Remote Add      ProducerCommission.My_RecentProducerCommissions                  ListView
```

I'd like to exclude these using the `.forceignore` file.

I've tried:

```
ClaimCoverage.All_ClaimCoverages.listView
All_ClaimCoverages.listView
```

Yet neither seems to work.

When I do this:

```
ClaimCoverage.listView
```

It excludes the `ListView` from the `status` output.

But when I run:

```
sfdx force:source:pull
```

I get error:

```
ERROR running force:source:pull:  Entity of type 'ListView' named 'InsurancePolicySurcharge.All_InsurancePolicySurcharges' cannot be found
Entity of type 'ListView' named 'ProducerCommission.My_RecentProducerCommissions' cannot be found
Entity of type 'ListView' named 'ClaimCoverage.My_RecentClaimCoverages' cannot be found
Entity of type 'ListView' named 'ClaimCoverage.All_ClaimCoverages' cannot be found
Entity of type 'ListView' named 'ProducerCommission.All_ProducerCommissions' cannot be found
Entity of type 'ListView' named 'ClaimPaymentSummary.My_RecentClaimPaymentSummaries' cannot be found
Entity of type 'ListView' named 'InsurancePolicyTransaction.My_RecentInsurancePolicyTransactions' cannot be found
Entity of type 'ListView' named 'ClaimPaymentSummary.All_ClaimPaymentSummaries' cannot be found
Entity of type 'ListView' named 'InsurancePolicySurcharge.My_RecentInsurancePolicySurcharges' cannot be found
Entity of type 'ListView' named 'InsurancePolicyTransaction.All_InsurancePolicyTransactions' cannot be found
```

**Question**

1. Why am I getting the error?
2. How can I correctly exclude the `ListView` such that it works as expected?